# MVC Adding more required field to the registration form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hello,

I have added 2 custom fields to my register view and amended the register controller and the Account model (see below) to make those 2 fields required.
I'm stuck at the point where:
 1 - My 2 extra fields are not validated even thought the password and username field are.
2 - My controller code is no longer executed.

Does someone have an idea?

My view is as follow:

```
    @model FEC.Models.RegisterModel
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Utilisateur";
    }

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        @{
            ViewBag.Title = "Roles";
            Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
        }

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">    </script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


        @* *************** Référence pour les menus déroulants Bootstrap ******************** *@
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/js/i18n/defaults-fr_FR.min.js"></script>
        @* *************** Fin référence pour les menus déroulants Bootstrap ******************** *@

        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0-alpha.4/handlebars.min.js"></script>



        <script type="text/javascript">
            templateRoles = null;
            templateUsers = null;

            //*************** Roles **************
            $(function () {
                templateRoles = Handlebars.compile($("#RolesTemplate").html());

                $(".scroll").click(function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top }, 1000);
                });

                $.getJSON("../Account/ListerRole", null, function (data) {
                    var result = templateRoles(data.list);
                    $("#RolesOutput").html(result);
                });
            });

            //*************** Utilisateurs **************
            $(function () {
                templateUsers = Handlebars.compile($("#UsersTemplate").html());

                $(".scroll").click(function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top }, 1000);
                });

                $.getJSON("../Account/GetListeUsers", { typeUsr: 'Administrateurs' }, function (data) {
                    var result = templateUsers(data.rows);
                    $("#UsersOutput").html(result);
                });
            });

            //*** Fonction pour remplir la liste déroulante des utilisateurs selon le rôle choisi ***
            function ChangementRole(choixRole) {
                //*** Appelle à une fonction "Ajax Callback" ***
                RemplirSelect(choixRole, function (retourSupPret) {
                    if (retourSupPret) {    //*** récupération de l'appel Ajax ***

                        //*** Utilisation de Handlebars pour traiter les données ***
                        var templateUsers = null;

                        templateUsers = Handlebars.compile($("#UsersTemplate").html());

                        $(".scroll").click(function (event) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top }, 1000);
                        });

                        var result = templateUsers(retourSupPret.rows);
                        $("#UsersOutput").html(result);     //*** Affiche le résulta dans l'espace à cet effet ***
                        $("#UsersOutput").selectpicker('refresh');  //*** Rafraichi le contrôle ***
                        //*** Reinitialise le contenu des contrôles cachés ***
                        $('#NomRole').val('');
                        $('#NomPersonne').val('');

                    };
                });
            };



            //*** Function AJAX CALLBACK pour retirer les noms des utilisateurs ***
            function RemplirSelect(typeUsr, callback) {
                var rep;
                var tUsr = null;

                switch (typeUsr) {
                    case 'Conseillers':
                        tUsr = "CS_";
                        break;
                    case 'Demandeurs':
                        tUsr = "DD_";
                        break;
                        //default:
                        //    msg = "La sélection n'est pas dans la liste!";
                        //    break;
                }

                //******************* Envoie la requête au serveur ***
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "../Account/GetListeUsers",
                    data: {
                        typeUsr: tUsr,
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    //******************* Liste écupérée avec succès ***********************
                    success: function (data, status) {
                        rep = data;
                        callback(rep);  //*** Renvoi du résultat à la function RemplirSelect
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        //******************* Liste non récupérée ********************
                        msg = "La liste des utilisateurs n'a pas pu être retiré!";
                        console.log(msg);
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        @* ********** Liste des Roles ************************* *@
        <script id="RolesTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
            <select id="cbxRolesOutput" class="selectpicker" title="Choisissez..." onchange="ChangementRole(this.value)">
                {{#each}}
                <option value="{{Text}}">{{Text}}</option>
                {{/each}}
            </select>
            <script>
                $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
            </script>
        </script>


        @* ********** Liste des demandeurs sans login ************************* *@
        <script id="UsersTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
            <select id="cbxUtilisateursOutput" class="selectpicker" title="Choisissez..." data-live-search="true" onchange="RecuppererRoleEtNomUtilisateur(this.value)">
                {{#each}}
                <option value="{{Code}}">{{Nom}}</option>
                {{/each}}
            </select>
            <script>
                $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
            </script>
        </script>
        <hgroup class="title">
            <h1>Menu utilisateurs: </h1>
            <h2>Créer un nouveau compte.</h2>
        </hgroup>
        <hr />

        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary()

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Formulaire d'enregistrement</legend>
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
                    </li>
                </ol>
                <table style="width: 70%;">
                    <tr>
                        <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.NomRole)</th>
                        <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.NomPersonne)</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div id="RolesOutput"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div id="UsersOutput"></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br />
                @* ******* Ajout de 2 champs cachés pour récupérer les valeurs: Rôle / Code Demandeur/Conseiller ******************** *@
                @* ********* Peut être remplacé par l'accès direct aux listes déroulantes avec @Html... ************************ *@
                @Html.Hidden("NomRole", "Demandeurs")
                @Html.Hidden("NomPersonne")
                <input type="submit" value="Valider" id="btnValider" />
            </fieldset>
        }
        <script>
            //*** Fonction pour assigner les rôle et nom d'utilisateur dans des contrôles chachées du formulaire ***
            function RecuppererRoleEtNomUtilisateur(codeDdeur) {
                //*** Récuoère la valeur du rôle choisi ***
                var r = document.getElementById("cbxRolesOutput");
                var strRole = r.options[r.selectedIndex].value;

                //*** Assigne les choix aux contrôles cachés ***
                $('#NomRole').val(strRole);
                $('#NomPersonne').val(codeDdeur);
            }

        </script>
        <style>
            li {
                padding: 10px 0px 5px 0px;
            }
        </style>

        @section Scripts {
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
        }

    </body>
    </html>
```

my controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
  [AllowAnonymous]
  [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
  public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
  {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
          bool erreur = false;

          // Attempt to register the user
          try
          {
              //************* Création du nouveau compte ********************
              WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);
              //WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
          }
          catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
          {
              erreur = true;
              ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
          }
          finally
          {
              //************* S'assurer que l'utilisateur a été créé *****************
              if (erreur == false)
              {
                  try
                  {
                      //***************** Association du nouveau compte d'utilisateur avec le rôle *************
                      RoleAddToUser(model.NomRole, model.UserName);
                      //***************** Association du nouveau compte d'utilisateur avec le demandeur / conseiller *************
                      var i = db.spGetUsrID(model.UserName).ToArray();
                      Conseillers_Demandeurs_Utilisateurs lienUtilDdeur_Cons = new Conseillers_Demandeurs_Utilisateurs()
                      {
                          UserId = (int)i[0],
                          Code_Demandeur_Conseiller = model.NomPersonne,
                          Actif_Inactif = true,
                          Dte_Saisie = DateTime.Now,
                          UserId1 = 1 //******************* UserId = loanDdeur.UserId;
                      };
                      db.Conseillers_Demandeurs_Utilisateurs.Add(lienUtilDdeur_Cons);
                      db.SaveChanges();
                  }

                  catch (Exception e)
                  {
                      throw e;
                  }
              }
          }
          return RedirectToAction("Account", "Register");
      }
      // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
      return View(model);
  }
```

My model:

```
             public class RegisterModel
     {
         [Required]
         [Display(Name = "Utilisateur")]
         public string UserName { get; set; }

         [Required]
         [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
         [DataType(DataType.Password)]
         [Display(Name = "Mot de passe")]
         public string Password { get; set; }

         [DataType(DataType.Password)]
         [Display(Name = "Confirmation du mot de passe")]
         [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Le mot de passe et sa confirmation ne correspondent pas.")]
         public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

         [Required]
         [Display(Name = "Role")]
         public string NomRole { get; set; }

         [Required]
         [Display(Name = "Personne")]
         public string NomPersonne { get; set; }

   }
```

Comment: You are misusing finally block. Since the exception is thrown finally is never executed because of the 'erreur' condition.

Comment: Put breakpoint in first line of controller and check step-by-step what is going on there.

Comment: have you updated database with new model?

Comment: Hello, I do have a breakpoint on the 1st line
My submit button does not even get there

Answer (score 0):

You might update the catch block as shown below:

```
...
catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
{
    erreur = true;
    ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
    return View(model);
}
```

On the other hand, I would also suggest you to use [jQuery Unobtrusive Validation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation/) so that validate the related field(s) before submitting the form.

Comment: Thanks,
That's what I finally did and had my fields checked within the form.
But still I can not get the submit button run my controller code.

Comment: You need to give the Controller and Action name in **Html.BeginForm(...)**.

Comment: On the other hand, if the answer is helpful for you please do not forget to select it as answer and vote up. Thanks...